# Iteration of an algorithm

Tags: perl, iteration

I wrote a program that load the data from a 2 columns file, made an algorithm calculation and then write the pair of elements in the file that have this coefficient and put them into an array called `@blackPair`. I would like to iterate N times the algorithm taking the datas from the file but not those that are in the `@blackPair` array.

I thought of something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $iter;
my $startNode;
my $endNode;
my %k;
my %end;
my %node;
my %edge;
my @blackPair=();
my $counts=0;
my $inputfile = "file3";
################# DATA ABSORTION

open(DAT,$inputfile) || die("Could not open file!");
while(<DAT>)
{
    my ($entry) = $_;
    chomp($entry);
    my ($startNode, $endNode) = split(/ /,$entry);
    $k{$endNode}++;
    $k{$startNode}++;
    $edge{$startNode}{$endNode}=1;
    $edge{$endNode}{$startNode}=1;
}
################# ALGORITHM
my $minCentrality=2;
foreach my $i (keys %edge) {
    foreach my $j (keys %{$edge{$i}}){
    my @couple =($j,$i);
    if($i<$j){
         if (($k{$i}-1) !=0 && ($k{$j}-1) !=0){
        my $triangleCount=0;
        @couple=($i,$j) if ($k{$i}<$k{$j});
        foreach (keys %{$edge{$couple[0]}}){
            $triangleCount++ if exists $edge{$couple[1]}{$_};
        }
        my $centrality=($triangleCount+1)/($k{$couple[0]}-1);
        if ($centrality<$minCentrality){
            $minCentrality=$centrality;
            @blackPair=@couple;
          } 
        }
      }
    }
}
foreach (@blackPair){
say; 
}
Close(DAT);
```

The file is the following:

```
1 2
1 3
1 4  
1 5
1 6
1 9
2 3
4 5
5 9
6 7
6 8
6 16
7 8
9 10
9 11
10 11
10 12
10 14
11 12
11 13
12 13
12 14
14 15
16 17
16 18
17 18
17 19
18 19
18 20
19 20
```

The first pair that appear in the `@blackPair` are the 6 and 1. After found them I would like that the program restart the search but avoiding to charge into the array the pairs 1 and 6. Doing that the second pair would be 6 and 16. I would like to repeat this process N times (for example N = 4). I thought to put before the `while(<DAT>)` in the "DATA ABSORTION" another `while(counts<=4){` and inside the `while(<DAT>)` an `if(<DATA> != @blackPair){`. There is what I thought

```
 while(counts <= 4) { 

 while(<DAT>)
 {
 if(<DAT> != @blackPair){
       my ($entry) = $_;
       chomp($entry);
       .....
 }
     #### ALGORITHM
 counts++;
 }
```

But it doesn't work. Any help?

After 4 iteration, in the `@blackPair` there should be the following pairs:

```
 6 1
 16 6
 9 1
 9 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<DAT> != @blackPair` is definitely not what you want.

- `!=` is for numerical comparison. You want to do either string comparison (the `ne` operator) or maybe use the smart match operator to check for list membership (`~~ \@blackPair`)
- but using the right operator won't really help you, because `@blackPair` already has mangled the input data (`@blackPair` might contain the elements `(6,1)`, corresponding to an original input line of `"1 6\n"`)

Instead, how about updating your graph in each iteration?

```
for my $count (1..4) {
    my $minCentrality = 2;
    ...

    say join " ", @blackPair;
    # now update the graph
    delete $edge{$blackPair[0]}{$blackPair[1]};
    delete $edge{$blackPair[1]}{$blackPair[0]};
    $k{$blackPair[0]}--;
    $k{$blackPair[1]}--;
} # next iteration
```

Comment: where exactly should I put the `say join " ", @blackPair;` code line in my code? I think it is a good idea

Comment: Use it to replace where you said `foreach (@blackPair) { say }`